# Check Ajax dataType using php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using this php function which checks if the request is an `Ajax` request or not which works fine.

```
function ajax_check() {
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

I want to know the `dataType` of the `Ajax` request. For example if the `dataType` is `json` or not. How can i achieve this using php?

Comment: you can't, that information is kept client-side. You'll have to send that information yourself either through a custom header or through a post/get var.

Comment: So i will have to pass a variable in all of my ajax request and check that variable on the php side?

Comment: You could try the `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']`. When trying with `dataType='JSON'` I got `application/json` and with `dataType='html'` I got `text/html`. But don't know if all servers will send you that information.

Comment: @KhawerZeshan Yes. Fortunately though you could do that all at once using a prefilter. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/

Comment: When your AJAX builds the URL you can append it with `www.sample.com/dostuff.php?datatype=json` and then use PHP to check for that `$_GET` variable

Answer (score -1):

You can check it in request headers

Accept  **application/json**, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01

there will be "text/html" or application/json